# Probleme with jQuery each() function and size image

Tags: jquery, image, function, each, addclass

Here's my problem, I have a portfolio where images appear dynamically :

```
<?php echo'<div class="real"><img src='".$pathReal."'></div>' ?>
```

They must resize in rapport by the size of the image.

So, in jQuery, I assign a class in rapport by the size of the image :

```
$(".real img").each(function(){
  var widthImage = $(this).width();
  var heightImage = $(this).height();

  if(widthImage > heightImage ){
     $(".real img").addClass('realHeight');
  }else{
     $(".real img").addClass('realWidth');
  }
});
```

But it's not working :

```
<img class="realHeight realWidth" src="img/1.jpg">
```

2 class are applied, when I want it to be one or the other.

(CSS):

```
.realWidth{width: 100%;}

.realHeight{height: 100%;}
```

Can someone help me, please ?

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Use instead: `$(this).addClass('realHeight');` and the same below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$(this)` in your loop to manipulate the right DOM Element (your image tag)

And use `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` to get the correct size of the image.

```
$(".real img").each(function(){
  var widthImage = $(this).naturalWidth;
  var heightImage = $(this).naturalHeight;

  if(widthImage > heightImage ){
     $(this).addClass('realHeight');
  }else{
     $(this).addClass('realWidth');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your echo seems to be wrong:

```
<?php echo'<div class="real"><img src='".$pathReal."'></div>' ?>
```

which should be like this:

```
<?php echo'<div class="real"><img src="'.$pathReal.'"></div>' ?>
```

---

Ans as you are looping so you can use `$(this)`

```
if(widthImage > heightImage ){
   $(this).addClass('realHeight');
}else{
   $(this).addClass('realWidth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of applying the class selectors inside each

```
$(".real img").each(function(){
  var widthImage = $(this).width();
  var heightImage = $(this).height();

  if(widthImage > heightImage ){
     $(this).addClass('realHeight');
  }else{
     $(this).addClass('realWidth');
  }
});
```

> $(".real img").addClass('realHeight');

This will apply realHeight class to all the images with class real. We dont want that